# Change x-axes label values in ggplot by utilizing different column value

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have the following code where I fit a log-linear model and plot the fit

```
r1 = lm(log10(df$size) ~ df$time + ...)
plt <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=time, y=size))+
    geom_point(size = 0.1) +    # Scatter
    geom_line(aes(y = 10^predict(r1))) +
    scale_y_log10()
```

The dataframe `df` contains 3 columns, namely `datetime`, `time` and `size`. `Time` is a normalized conversion from `datetime` such that r1 can take float values instead of datetimes. Datetimes are incremented by 10 minutes.

| datetime | time | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 4 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:10 | 600 | 34 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:20 | 1200 | 12 |

The problem I am phasing now is that I want to replace the x-axes values by the `datetime` value instead of the `time` value.

We can use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$time, labels = df$datetime)`, however, this will put x labels at every point. Instead, I want to use somehow the axes labels selected by default (probably using `waiver()`) and then select the value at the same index from `df$datetime`.

I tried using [Manual addition of x-axes in ggplot with new labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040998/manual-addition-of-x-axes-in-ggplot-with-new-labels), however the difference for me is that I have another column with datetimes that I want to utilize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Z.Lin, replacing the labels for the breaks with values from another column could in general be easily achieved but will only work if there is a corresponding value in your data for each of the default breaks set by ggplot2, which in general (see your example data) is not the case.

One option would be to use interpolation to set the `labels` using e.g. `Hmisc::approxExtrap`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

r1 <- lm(log10(df$size) ~ df$time)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = size)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) + # Scatter
  geom_line(aes(y = 10^predict(r1))) +
  scale_y_log10() 

p +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = function(x) {
      x[!is.na(x)] <- Hmisc::approxExtrap(df$time, df$datetime, xout = x[!is.na(x)])$y
      as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01")
    }
  ) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(r = 50))
```

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(
  datetime = c(
    "2022-07-01 00:00:00",
    "2022-07-01 00:00:10", 
    "2022-07-01 00:00:20"
  ),
  time = c(0L, 600L, 1200L),
  size = c(4L, 34L, 12L)
)

df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime)
```

[image]

Comment: This did the trick! Is there also a way to round them down to dates? I tried adding `p + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d/%m")` but that gave an error

Answer (score 0):

Since `time` is numeric, the default axis breaks selected by `waiver()` may not have exact match with the values in `df`. Since the datetime variable in your dataset increments by a fixed amount in each row, perhaps the following can work for you?

```
df.sliced <- df %>%
  slice(round(seq(1, n(),
                  length.out = 5)))

plt + scale_x_continuous(breaks = df.sliced$time, labels = df.sliced$datetime)
```

I used 5 as the number of breaks for convenience; the actual calculation performed by ggplot to determine the number of breaks can get rather complicated.